# Why can't Visual Studio 2013 determine the workspace for my solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Earlier today the TFS server where I work went down. As a result, when I tried going into visual studio 2013 to work on a project that managed though TFS Visual Studio detected that TFS was inaccessible and accessed the solution in offline mode. Later on in the morning the server was rebooted and was online and operational. However, when I try to go online with the solution I get the error message stating "Unable to determine the workspace for this solution". So I went ahead and verified that the workspace is correct with all the bindings from the associated source control folder to that of my local folders. So to try and fix the issue I did the following steps:

1. I completely disassociated the solution from source control even though its offline.
2. Rebinded the solution to source control. At this point all locks were visible on the solution and the files that were checked out.
3. I got the latest version for the project and and updated my local solution.

Rebinding the solution worked to fix my initial issue. However, every time I exit visual studio 2013 and go back into the solution it loses all the bindings and it's unable to determine the workspace for the solution. Has anyone ran into this before? Is there something that I am overlooking? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Please Note, I have read though some of the posts already on stack-overflow and I have not found one that addresses the issue with Visual Studio losing the bindings on each start-up.

Answer (score 3):

Quit Visual Studio.
There is a Registry-Entry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\Instances\\[[NameYourOfTFSServerHere]]\Collections\\[[NameOfYourProjectCollectionHere]]
```

Change **Reg_Dword** `Offline` from `1 to 0`

Delete the `.suo` file of the Solution

Reopen your Solution should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "show hidden files" is enabled, then delete the .suo file in the solution's folder (while VS is closed, of course)

Answer (score 0):

Quit all Visual Studio instances and delete TFS cache at "c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache"

Comment: I removed the cache and closed all instances of Visual Studio. However, all bindings are still lost when solution is re binded and Visual Studio is closed and reopened. What I ultimately had to do was do a full restore of my development environment. While thats not a true fix, it was a last resort as Visual Studio was not cooperating at any level. Thanks for responding to my original post.